# rxJs callback with observable being asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a map operation in my rxjs flow

```
streaming.map((data) => {
  //example async call
  methodCall.then((response) => {
    return data.test
  })
})
.filter((value) => ...);
```

The thing is filter is called before data.test is returned naturally. So I tried converting it to switchMap and returning an observable

```
streaming.switchMap((data) => {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    //example async call
    methodCall.then((response) => {
      observer.next(data.test);
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
})
.filter((value) => ......);
```

I assumed that IN THIS case since we are returning an observable with explicit timing on next is called the filter would be called ONLY after the observer.complete is called but filter was called prematurely with the value variable undefined.

How would I accomplish this normally using rxJs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a return statement or something. That's why it gives you unexpected results. The `switchMap()` operator subscribes to the Observable returned from its callback and reemits all its items until another Observable is returned. It doesn't wait for complete notification.

This should simulate your example:

```
function methodCall() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(123);
  }, 1000));
}

Observable.of(42)
  .do(value => console.log('start: ' + value))
  .switchMap((data) => {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      //example async call
      methodCall().then((response) => {
        observer.next(response);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  })
  .filter(value => true)
  .subscribe(value => console.log('next: ' + value));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/focili/2/edit?js,console

Notice that `123` is emitted when the Promise resolves.

By the way, maybe you don't need to use `switchMap()` at all. RxJS 5 treats Observables, Promises, arrays, array-like objects, etc. the same way. This means you can interchange Observables for any of the mentioned above. For example you can use just `concatMap()` and the result is going to be the same:

```
function methodCall() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(123);
  }, 1000));
}

Observable.of(42)
  .do(value => console.log('start: ' + value))
  .concatMap(value => methodCall())
  .filter(value => true)
  .subscribe(value => console.log('next: ' + value));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/wipofiv/2/edit?js,console

Notice that `concatMap()` receives a Promise but it still works as expected a you don't even need to transform it into an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can transform `Promise` to `Observable` with `fromPromise`

```
streaming.switchMap((data) => Observable.fromPromise(methodCall))
         .filter((value) => ...);
```

This does all ugly job and you just enjoy RxJS programming.

Probably before `filter` you would need to apply some `.map` to return `data.test` instead of `data`